# Grammatical Correctness of the Phrase "interpretations on _____"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

I am aware that the commonly used preposition following the word "interpretations" is "of", but is using "on" also grammatically correct? I have seen the word "on" being used on several occasions.

For example:

1. There are various interpretations of his actions.
2. There are various interpretations on his actions.

If possible, please provide evidence for the answer and also examples from English literature.

Comment: You say *I have seen the word "on" being used on several occasions.* Could you please give examples with the source and context?

Comment: From a wiktionary search (I copied and pasted the phrases in which the usage was present; I'm not exactly sure what context to give):

["Historical interpretations on Napoleon"](https://www.history.org.uk/secondary/module/8669/teacher-fellowship-programme-teaching-the-age-of/9448/historical-interpretations-on-napoleon)

["New interpretations on Celtic and Non–Celtic personal names"](https://www.academia.edu/1318156/Sifting_the_evidence_New_interpretations_on_Celtic_and_Non_Celtic_personal_names_of_western_Hispania_in_the_light_of_phonetics_composition_and_suffixation)

Comment: But the first source is an educational website with a page discussing Napoleon, and the second was an academic paper.

Comment: The first is a title "Historical interpretations on Napoleon". Titles and headlines are not subject to normal syntactical guidance - "Napoleon" in this context **on** means "***on the subject of** the life, times, and military and political history of Napoleon*." in this use, "on" it is the same as  "Historical interpretations **on** the Punic Wars." Or "An essay **on** Publius Quinctilius Varus." In your example **2**, "on" would be inappropriate. __ **Of** carries the general meaning of "*associated with*" and your example **1** is correct.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the correct preposition to use after *interpretation* is *of*. We thus speak of the interpretations of a Biblical passage, of a provision of the U.S. Constitution, of a dream, of a complex work of art. Generally, using *on* in place of *of* in such a context, can be dismissed as simply a mistake.

Why might one, nevertheless, sometimes want to use *on* in such a context? The key is that we sometimes speak of **imposing** an interpretation **on** something that does not obviously call for an interpretation. Somebody's actions (the OP's own example) may, at first sight, seem unremarkable, and then somebody may offer an account that purports to reveal something unobvious about their purposes—in such a case, we can say that an interpretation has been imposed on these actions. There is then a natural step from speaking about imposing an interpretation on the actions to speaking of it as an interpretation on the actions. Whether this step is to be welcomed or deplored is likely to be a matter of opinion, but it is certainly understandable.

Comment: So is using "on" in that sentence still grammatically correct? Or do you mean that it is disputed?

Comment: @PubliusQuinctiliusVarus, using *on* in this way is probably too rare for its correctness to be actually disputed. If you were to use it, chances are that you would make at least some people cringe; if you want to make sure that you don't cause such a reaction, use *of*.